# About Keyboard Language support for Malayalam in Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

For those don't know about ***Malayalam*** or ***Kerala*** ;
Malayalam is the language spoken in Kerala, which is a state in **India.**

My question is about **Malayalam** Keyboard layout in Windows 10.

I am currently using keyboard in windows for typing Malayalam Language. But I'm unable to type in characters like ൾ ൽ ർ ണ്‍ ൻ ,etc.

In Linux it is possible.
For example,
ര്+] would give ർ.

What is the key in windows for this?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the pattern that should be typed in order to get chillaksharangal using Malayalam unicode keyboard in windows :

ല്‍ = ല് + (Ctrl + Shift + 1) 
ന്‍ = ന് + (Ctrl + Shift + 1)

and similarly the rest.